# Python Xlib _NET_DESKTOP_NAMES

Tags: python, xlib, window-managers

Im writing a window manager as a pet project and have been trying to set the names of each desktop so that my [candybar](https://github.com/Lokaltog/candybar/%22candybar%22) will be
able to display them.

Here is the relevent code:

```
sting = '! @ #'
Utils.root_window().change_property(atoms['_NET_DESKTOP_NAMES'],   Xatom.STRING, 32, string)
```

I've tried many types of string formating heres just a few:

```
['!','@','#']
u'! @ #'
'!@#'
\x00!\x00@\x00#
!\x00@\x00#\x00
```

I found alot of information about setting atoms on the web but very little about this particular atom

ps. I am able to set _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS and _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP correctly

pro**strong text**

Comment: I think `32` is wrong there. Try `8`. That said `_NET_DESKTOP_NAMES` is supposed to be `UTF8_STRING[]` and I don't know that python supports that type directly (which may be a problem here).

Comment: First thank you I changed 32 to 8 Unfortunately you appear to be right about Python not supporting UTF8 none of the WM's I'm using as reference set any UTF8 atoms...would you happen to know the most 'pythonic' way to do this outside of xlib then? With out using Pyxcb

Comment: This seems to be what you want https://github.com/BurntSushi/xpybutil/blob/master/xpybutil/ewmh.py#L596 Though I question the need for that null-termination bit (but it might be necessary).